# Scheduling powershell script to run on server - finding powershell.exe

Tags: powershell, scheduler

I'm trying to schedule a powershell script to run on a server.  I used $env:PSModulePath and one of the powershell locations is c:\windows\system32\windowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules.  When I look in that location, there is no Powershell.exe there.  I wanted to use that for the Application name in the system scheduler.  How can I verify that Powershell.exe is there?  I also wanted to find which version each one is for all of the powershell versions seen with $env command above to verify which would be the 5.1 version that I tested on my computer with.

[env:PSModulePath](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/where-the-powershell-modules-are-stored)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`c:\windows\system32\windowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules` is the Modules directory

`$psHome` returns the .exe location